# how to parse JSON with field properties in Android with GSON

Tags: android, gson

The vaules with @ are properties of the field street... I have never seen this before in json so and I am a little bit lost.

```
"street":{"$":"Stadhouderskade","@label":"Street","@id":"123"}
```

Same thing in XML will be:

```
<street id="123" label="Street">Stadhouderskade</street>
```

How can I get this field values using gson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All* values are properties of street, objects have nothing like XML does. In XML there are "two kinds of properties":

- attributes which can only be strings
- content which may be structured

Unlike JSON this doesn't map to objects directly. So just use a [FieldNamingStrategy](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.java?r=411) which maps "$" to "name", and "@something" to "something" with a class like

```
class Street {
    String name;
    String label; // maybe should be omitted as "Street" is quite useless here
    int id;
}
```

Or is there another problem with the JSON? What I wrote must be enough for the part shown.